# Critical points in Cauchy problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

I'm solving Cauchy problem: $$y'+y\tan(x)=(\cos(x))^2$$ $$y(\pi/4)=1/2$$
The answer I get: $y=sin(x)cos(x)$. Please help to find critical points, need for phase portrait it.

Comment: Phase portrait analysis of a non-autonomous 1D equation usually doesn't make sense. One can see that by looking at the "lifted" system, where you parametrize by $t$ and set $x'=1$: now you wind up with a 2D autonomous equation, but it has no critical points since $x'=1$. Moreover the sign of $y'$ is a bona fide function of both $x$ and $y$, so you can't even predict the direction of motion by only knowing the current value of $y$.